# How to improve the quality of function ‘image.save()’？

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I saved the image to the clipboard, and when I read the image information from the clipboard and saved it locally, the image quality changed. How can I save it to maintain the original high quality?

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
im = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
im.save('somefile.png','PNG')
```

I tried adding the parameter `'quality=95'` in `im.save()`, but it didn't work. The original image quality is 131K, and the saved image is 112K.

Comment: What about real image quality not size? Was it decreased?

Comment: @Alderven Yes, the real image quality is 131K, and the saved image is 112K. Image quality reduced by 19K. But I don't understand why the quality of PNG images is lost.

Comment: How you have got `131K` and `112K`?

Comment: Maybe I didn't express my meaning clearly. I mean, the original size of the image is `131KB`, and the size of the image obtained after saving by the Python function `im.save()` becomes `112KB`. Is there a better function to make the PNG image size the same?

Comment: How did the "file" get into the clipboard?

Comment: @TheTahaan: My program function is to monitor the clipboard and save the contents of the clipboard. So when the image is copied, the image is saved to the clipboard. At this point I need to save the original image.

Comment: So it depends on how the image got into the clipboard - the clipboard contents might not be identical to the original file, especially if it is a screenshot.

Comment: If you have an image, in a file, on your computer and you display it on the screen and capture the screen, you cannot recreate the original file. The original may have comments or copyright information in it, it may say which camera it was captured on and when and none of that will be in the screenshot so the file saved from the screenshot cannot possibly be the same.

Comment: I know what you want to say, but here is the direct click on the `copy` button instead of the screenshot. If you click the `copy` button directly and then click `paste`, then the image is the same size as the original image. But if you use `image.save()` to read data from the clipboard and save it, you will have problems.

Comment: There is a very fundamental difference between asking an operating system to make a byte-for-byte identical copy of something on a disk, and asking a program from one manufacturer to read and interpret an image, adapt it to match the capabilities of your graphics card, do colour matching, resize and display it, followed by capturing it to a clipboard that may or may not support transparency, may or may not be 8/16-bit and then asking a different piece of software from a different manufacturer to re-encode that image and save it to disk.

Comment: It's kind of like giving an engineer a Rolls Royce, all the plans, tools and production lines and asking him to make a copy of it, versus giving him a glossy photo of a Rolls Royce and asking him to make you a real one.

Comment: I agree with Mark, hence my questions above.  What is in a clipboard really depends on a lot of factors.  If you want to copy the file, do that:  Copy the file.  If you want to save the clipboard-contents, live with the fact that there are two conversions, one from the original data to a format saved into the clipboard, and another where the clipboard is parsed and processed to create a new image, and you will probably never have full control over those: you depend on other program's behaviour in the first instance and on 3rd party libraries in the second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size of the file is not directly related to the quality of the image. It also depends on how efficiently the encoder does its job. As it is PNG, the process is lossless, so you don't need to worry - the quality is retained.

Note that the `quality` parameter has a different meaning when saving JPEG files versus PNG files:

- With JPEG files, if you specify a lower quality you are effectively allowing the encoder to discard more information and give up image quality in return for a smaller file size.
- With PNG, your encoding and decoding are lossless. The quality is a hint to the decoder as to how much time to spend compressing the file (always losslessly) and about the types of filtering/encoding that may suit best. It is more akin to the parameter to `gzip` like `--best` or `--fast`.

Further information about PNG format is [here on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics).

---

Without analysing the content of the two images it is impossible to say why the sizes differ - there could be many reasons:

- One encoder may have noticed that the image contains fewer than 256 colours and so has decided to use a palette whereas the other may not have done. That could make the images size differ by a factor of 3 times, yet the quality would be identical.
- One encoder may use a larger buffer and spend longer looking for repeating patterns in the image. For a simplistic example, imagine the image was 32,000 pixels wide and each line was the same as the one above. If one encoder uses an 8kB buffer, it can never spot that the image just repeats over and over down the page so it has to encode every single line in full, whereas an encoder with a 64kB buffer might just be able to use 1 byte per line and use the PNG filtering to say *"same as line above"*.
- One encoder might decide, on grounds of simplicity of code or for lack of code space, to always encode the data in a 16-bit version even if it could use just 8 bits.
- One encoder might decide it is always going to store an alpha layer even if it is opaque because that may make the code/data cleaner simpler.
- One encoder may always elect to do no filtering, whilst the other has the code required to do `sub`, `up`, `average` or `Paeth` filtering.
- One encoder may not have enough memory to hold the entire image, so it may have to use a simplistic approach to be assured that it can handle whatever turns up later in the image stream.

I just made these examples up - don't take them was gospel - I am just trying to illustrate some possibilities.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I know that PNG is lossless, but why is the image still smaller during the save process? My demand is to save the original image, although the quality is the same, the size is smaller.

Comment: I have added some more information to my answer. You seem to continue to be under the illusion that bigger files mean better quality and that simply is not true. Imagine a 1,000x1,000 image that is solid red - I have described that in 25 bytes. It is no more accurate to store a 3MB image with all those repeated rgb(255,0,0) bytes. The quality is the same - the size is different.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, it is very helpful to me. But my demand is to implement a program code that saves the original image. What function do I need to use? Maybe the function of `Image.save()` will have the problem you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

To reproduce an exact copy of file from a clipboard, the only way is if the clipboard contains a byte-for-byte copy of the original.  This does not happen when the content comes from the "Copy" function in a program.

In theory a program could be created to do that by setting a blob-type object with a copy of the original file, but that would be highly inefficient and defeat the purpose of the clipboard.

Some points:
- When you copy into the clipboard using the file manager, the clipboard will have a reference to the original file (not the entire file which can potentially be much larger than ram)
- Most programs will set the clipboard contents to some "useful version" of the displayed or selected data.  This is very much subject to interpretation by the creator of the program.
- Parsing the clipboard content when reading an image is again subject to the whims of the library used to process the data and pack it back into an image format.

Generally if you want to copy a file exactly you will be better off just copying the original file.

Having said that:  Evaluate the purpose of the copy-paste process and decide whether the data you get from the clipboard is "good enough" for the intended purpose.  This obviously depends on what you want to use it for.